# How to find out exactly which process was killed by OOM killer?

Tags: linux, oom

OOM killer just killed some process. I can know about it when the value of `grep oom_kill /proc/vmstat` increases.

How would I know which process exactly was killed (name, pid, owner and so on) and when exactly (timestamp)?

Answer (score 2):

The crude, but easy way to know details on recent OOM-kill is to grep everywhere (proper log path may differ from distrib to distrib):

```
sudo dmesg -T | grep -Ei 'killed process|oom.killer'
sudo grep -Ei 'killed process|oom.killer' /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog 2>/dev/null
```

`.` means "any character" in regexp for `grep`, so it will find lines containing both "oom-killer" and "oom killer".

`2>/dev/null` on the end is needed to get rid of the "No such file or directory" error, if there is no such logfiles in your system.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 and helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look for entries from OOM killer events in the logs.

```
sudo grep -i "oom-killer" /var/log/messages
```

Result looks something like this:

```
kernel: [timestamp] Out of memory: Kill process [process_name] ([process_pid]), UID [user_id]/[username], VmSize:[memory_size] kB, VmRSS:[resident_memory_size] kB, MemLimit:[memory_limit] kB
```

Comment: … [or `/var/log/syslog`](https://askubuntu.com/q/26237/693277). And some related events may be described with `OOM killer` or so, thus `grep -i 'oom.kill'` may be a good idea.